# Referring to a proxy'd this inside a class getter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following contrived code:

```
class Animal {
  get age() {
    return this.baseage + 10;
  }

  age2() {
    return this.baseage + 10;
  }
}

const handler = {
  "get": function(target, key) {
     if (key === "baseage") {
       return 20;
     }

     return target[key];
  }
};

const animal = new Proxy(new Animal(), handler);

console.log(animal.age);
console.log(animal.age2());
```

Which produces

```
NaN
30
```

On node 6.11.0.

I would expect the code in the class getter, specifically `this.baseage`, to go through the proxy's handler too, but that does not seem to be the case. Is there any reason for it?

Answer (score 2):

`return target[key];` is *not* the same behavior as the default `get` handler. This is the cause of the broken `get age` function.

```
const handler = {
  "get": function(target, key) {
     if (key === "baseage") {
       return 20;
     }

     return target[key];
  }
};
```

should be

```
const handler = {
  "get": function(target, key, receiver) {
     if (key === "baseage") {
       return 20;
     }

     return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
  }
};
```

When you do `target[key]` you are calling the `get age(){`, but you are calling it with `target` as `this`, which is the `new Animal` object, not the proxy. Since the Proxy object is the one that handles `baseage`, not the `Animal`, you get back `undefined`.

In this example, `receiver` is the actual proxy object, so you could potentially do `receiver[key]` to have your snippet work, but there are *tons* more edge cases that you'd still not be handling in a general way.

Every single `Proxy` handler function has a `Reflect.XX` version that exposes the default behavior. Whenever you're writing a proxy and just want it to act like it normally would, you should be using `Reflect`.